# MOSFET circuit question

Tags: mosfet

Just took a job doing component level repair on computers, mostly laptops, but we don't use schematics.  The boards have many 8 pin dual MOSFETS, and of course sometime they go bad, shorting from source to drain.  This is verified by taking the component out of circuit to test.

However, some of are hooked up to a short circuit by design as part of a circuit.  They read source to drain short until taken out and found to be good.

Given they are being used as simple switches, I am having trouble understanding where they are used in that configuration, hooked across a short by design.

Any examples of circuits that use this configuration in computers, such as laptops, would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is off topic. That being said, if you want to find if a transistor is bad or not remove it from the board and then test it.

Comment: There are parts such as switchmode transformer coils that will close to zero ohms unless one takes particular care in the measurement. In-circuit measurements require knowledge to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is a short somewhere else. I don't know of any design where you want to short Vdd to gnd. Something else is going bad and shorting your power supply to ground. Try tracing the short all the way to where it's produced.

If when you remove the mosfet from the circuit, the short **in the circuit disappears**, then the mosfet is bad. But if the short stays **in the circuit** after you remove the mosfet, then something else is causing the short to gnd.

Once you prove that the mosfets are good, I would isolate the different voltage rails (1V8, 3V3, 5V or whatever voltages you have) to find when the short disappears, that'll give a clue of which circuits to look at. That way you can narrow down your search.

Comment: I think the circuits in question, with the MOSFETs that test bad in circuit but ok out, appear to often be connected to inductors.